# unexpected elseif on wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

Hi doing some code in wordpress with changing languages but it's doesen't work the problem somewhere in elseif, can somebody help me please?

```
        <?php 
            if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'): 
            $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
                'post_type' => 'shapes_en', 
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'asc',
                ) 
            );
            if ($loop):
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='he'):
            $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
                'post_type' => 'shape', 
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'asc',
                ) 
            );
            if ($loop):
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  
            endif;
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('idustry-thumbnail'); ?></a>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title()?></a></h3>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; 
            endif;?>
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? You need to be more specific.

Comment: You need to insert a `endwhile;` statement.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF) in /home/darplast/public_html/wp-content/themes/darplast/index.php on line 20

Comment: You inserted the `endwhile;` at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

The `while:` syntax requires an `endwhile;`, otherwise it is not known where the `while` block stops. Because of the absense of the `endwhile;` statement, PHP thinks the `elseif;` is still inside the while loop, and thus `elseif;` is unexpected.

[The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php):

> In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon (:) and the closing brace to *endif;*, *endwhile;*, *endfor;*, *endforeach;*, or *endswitch;*, respectively.

Change your code to this:

```php
if ($loop):
    while ($loop->have_posts()):
        $loop->the_post();
    endwhile;
elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'he'):
...
```

I don't know if using alternative syntax is required when writing a [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) template, but unless you are writing a template, I suggest using the normal syntax with curling brackets, because it is often easier to read.

```php
if ($loop) {
    while ($loop->have_posts()) {
        $loop->the_post();
    }
}
elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'he') {
...
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/darplast/public_html/wp-content/themes/darplast/index.php on line 55